# AWS Security Groups misunderstanding

Tags: amazon-web-services, security-groups

I have 2 windows server instances in AWS, both have their firewalls disabled.

They are in the same VPC and the same availability zone.

I'm simply trying to allow these servers to ping each other.

Each server has it's own security group. If I create rules such that pings are allowed from the other servers internal IP, then the pings work.

If I create rules such that pings are allowed from the other servers security group, the pings don't work.

Is creating rules based on a source IP the best way of doing this? I've always thought that to allow traffic between instances you allow access based on security groups?

Not sure if my understanding is wrong?

Comment: Defining it by security group ID should be the recommended way to define this and it has worked for me in the past. I would double check the rule you created to make sure the only difference is IP vs SG ID.  Also make sure you are creating both outbound and inbound rules, though outbound may default to "allow all" so it may not be necessary.

Comment: I always define by security group rather than IP, it's simpler. Both methods should work.